# Can I get iOS analytics without including mysterious closed-source libraries into my app?

Tags: ios, google-analytics, analytics, flurry, flurry-analytics

I want to collect very simple analytics about my app (session count, monthly active users, maybe a list of events corresponding to each screen open), but the systems I've found all require integrating an opaque binary library into my project.

Does anyone know of any iOS analytics systems that *don't* have this shortcoming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Analytics with an os library: https://github.com/ksmandersen/GoogleReporter

> Easily integrate Google Analytics into your iOS, macOS, and tvOS app without downloading any of the Google SDKs.

Mixpanel is also open-source and doesn't include any static libraries.
https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-iphone